# zetbaitsu/Compressor resolution not working

Tags: android, image-processing, compression, image-compression

So I am using zetbaitsu/Compressor library for image compression and resize the image but when I try to compress the image dimension of original dimension (3503 x 5254) the result for the following height value are as follow

800,700,600 will give the resolution of (876 x 1314) which is 1/8 of the original size and

when the value is 900+ the resolution of the image gets (1752 x2627) which is 1/2 of the original.

So is there any way to change the size exactly as per our standards as I tried other similar question i was not able to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

It's actuallly only possible by creating your own custom constraint for this library.
The usual resolution constraint of this lib ([Methodcall](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor/blob/master/compressor/src/main/java/id/zelory/compressor/constraint/ResolutionConstraint.kt))([Method declaration](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor/blob/master/compressor/src/main/java/id/zelory/compressor/Util.kt)) uses the following method ([found here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)):

```java
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

So it reduces the size of the image by 2 as long as it is bigger than the requested size.

The easiest way to change this is probably to create your own custom constraint and change the `calculateInSampleSize()` call to your own method calculating the modifier for the exact size.

Edit:
This is a sample constraint, how it should work. I couldn't test so far, but this should give you an idea how it works:

```java
    public class SizeContstraint implements Constraint
    {

        private int _height;

        // Resulting image height
        public SizeContstraint(int height)
        {
            _height = height;
        }

        // Checks, if the constraint is valid
        @Override
        public boolean isSatisfied(@NotNull final File file)
        {
            // Get the file options (height, width, e.t.c)
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            // Calculate if the current image is bigger than the necessary size
            return calculateExactSizeModifier(options, _height) > 1;
        }

        // This method is only called, if the constraint is invald (the image is too big)
        @NotNull
        @Override
        public File satisfy(@NotNull final File file)
        {
            int height = _height;
            int width = 0;

            // Get the file options (height, width, e.t.c)
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

            // Get the size modifier to be able to resize the image
            int modifier = calculateExactSizeModifier(options, height);

            // Calculate the width using the modifier
            width = options.outWidth / modifier;

            // Resize the file into a bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = id.zelory.compressor.UtilKt.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file, width, height);
            // Write the bitmap back into the file
            return id.zelory.compressor.UtilKt.overWrite(file, bmp, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100);
        }

        private int calculateExactSizeModifier(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqHeight)
        {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int modifier = 1;

            // Calculate modifier if height bigger than requested height
            if (height > reqHeight)
            {
                modifier = height / reqHeight;
            }

            return modifier;
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried changing what you said but no results it is still giving the same results

Comment: It took me some time to update. I've added a Constraint sample how it could work.